# When do you use PHP's __soapCall() vs __doRequest()?

Tags: php, soap

I want to  clarify what the use cases are for PHP's `SoapClient::__soapCall()` vs `SoapClient::__doRequest()` methods.

As I understand it, both send SOAP requests to a SOAP endpoint with the main difference being that `doRequest()` sends a string of raw (SOAP) XML which you have composed yourself using the `DOMDocument` class, string concatenation or something else whereas `soapCall()` creates the request XML for you from an array of parameters that you pass to it?

Is this correct and are there any other thoughts on when to use which?